# Modifying environment variable for a process with scala.sys.process?

Tags: scala

I want to run my process from scala, with several environment variables modified. For example:

```
Seq("bash","echo $asdf") !
```

and $asdf set to some value. Is there a way to do this from scala?

EDIT:

The closest I got to it so far:

```
val pb = new java.lang.ProcessBuilder("bash","echo $asdf")
pb.environment.put("asdf","value") }
val p = pb.start()
io.Source.fromInputStream(p.getInputStream).getLines.toList.foreach(println)
p.waitFor()
```

But this is ugly.

Comment: BTW, You can do it just like you do in Java:

`import java.util._`   
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo $PATH")`

Comment: @om-nom-nom You can omit parens. In fact, see `sys.runtime`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
Process(Seq("bash", "-c", "echo $asdf"), None, "asdf" -> "Hello, world!").!
```

See [Process](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.sys.process.Process$).

Comment: For the first time ever, my answer is longer than the Sobral answer it duplicates. Ironically, this answer more precisely answers what the duplicate question was probably trying to ask. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18411947/1296806

Comment: @som-snytt This was a rather poor answer of mine. Shame on me! :)

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work, it tries to interpret "echo $asdf" as an executable -- gives `bash: echo $asdf: No such file or directory`.

Comment: I got it working adding a -c: `Process(Seq("bash", "-c", "echo $asdf"), None, "asdf" -> "Hello, world!").!`