# How to set environmental variable from Scala?

Tags: scala

I need to set environmental variable (PATH) from Scala.

I tried this:

```
val cmd = Seq("export", "PATH='bla'")
cmd.lines
```

but I got error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "export": error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$Simple.run(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:68)
at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.lines(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:140)
at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.lines(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:106)
at .<init>(<console>:12)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at .<init>(<console>:11)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at $print(<console>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:704)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:914)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:546)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:577)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:543)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.reallyInterpret$1(ILoop.scala:694)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:745)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:651)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine$1(ILoop.scala:542)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:550)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:822)
at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.main(ILoop.scala:851)
at xsbt.ConsoleInterface.run(ConsoleInterface.scala:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:73)
at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.console(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:64)
at sbt.Console.console0$1(Console.scala:23)
at sbt.Console$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Console.scala:24)
at sbt.TrapExit$.executeMain$1(TrapExit.scala:33)
at sbt.TrapExit$$anon$1.run(TrapExit.scala:42)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
    ... 35 more
```

Is there some other way to do that?

Comment: Are you trying to launch another process from Scala with the properties set, or are you trying to get the properties to persist after the Scala program exits?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9443190/1296806, which has an answer as terse as mine below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Example from doc for `sys.process.Process`:

```
apply("java", new java.ioFile("/opt/app"), "CLASSPATH" -> "library.jar")
```

Edit for more helpful verbiage:

That is, you specify the env when you spawn a child process.

The environment of the current process is read-only; see `System.getenv`, or compare the abstractions `sys.props` and `sys.env`.

The fact that a shell augments the environment it bestows on subshells with exported variables is a shell convention.  See 3.7.4 in the bash reference, for example:

> On invocation, the shell scans its own environment and creates a
>   parameter for each name found, automatically marking it for export to
>   child processes. Executed commands inherit the environment. The export
>   and ‘declare -x’ commands allow parameters and functions to be added
>   to and deleted from the environment. If the value of a parameter in
>   the environment is modified, the new value becomes part of the
>   environment, replacing the old. The environment inherited by any
>   executed command consists of the shell's initial environment, whose
>   values may be modified in the shell, less any pairs removed by the
>   unset and ‘export -n’ commands, plus any additions via the export and
>   ‘declare -x’ commands.

This is the first time my answer was longer than [the Daniel Sobral answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9444391/1296806) it duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

'export' isn't an executable, it's a shell built-in command.  If you're trying to set the path in the parent shell, well, you can't.  You can set it for a new shell that you execute.  This is really more of a unix FAQ.