# Scala: Unable to set environment variable

Tags: scala, set, environment-variables

Friends,

I'm trying to set the environment variable "asdf" in my Scala shell, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443190/modifying-environment-variable-for-a-process-with-scala-sys-process)

These are my commands:

```
scala> import scala.sys.process.Process
import scala.sys.process.Process

scala> Process(Seq("bash", "-c", "echo $asdf"), None, "asdf" -> "Hello, world!").!
Hello, world!
res18: Int = 0
```

But when i try to read the environment variable back:

```
scala> sys.env.get("asdf")
res19: Option[String] = None
```

The output says "None". How do i properly set my environment variable **in the current session**?

PS - Please do not downvote this; i'm trying really hard but unable to get past my issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Scala, you are just misunderstanding the situation.  The map at the end of the line

```
scala> Process(Seq("bash", "-c", "echo $asdf"), None, "asdf" -> "Hello, world!").!
```

doesn't change the environment of of *this* process, the one you are typing into; it changes the environment of the child process that the `Process()` function creates.

Comment: Is there a way to set my environment variable for the **current** process?

Comment: @JimitRaithatha -- nope

Answer (score 6):

It is not permitted for a Scala/Java process to modify its own environment. You can use the `scala.util.Properties` object to inspect environmental variables and properties. (Docs are [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Properties$.html).) The properties can be added/removed/changed but the environmentals cannot.