# Add environment variable

Tags: scala

I´m trying to add a new environment variable in my test but I see that

```
sys.env
```

is an immutable map, so I cannot see a way to add a new env var.

Any idea how?

Comment: can you try using `sys.env ++ Map("abc" -> "xyz")`

Comment: sys.env ++ Map("abc" -> "xyz") return a new map, so how do you asign that new map to the actual sys.env

Comment: No you can not assign it back it `sys.env`. You need to store new `Map` to another variable.

Comment: yeah that´s why is not an option here. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you are testing should not depend on `sys.env` directly. Make `environment: Map[String, String]` a parameter - then you can pass any data you want in for testing, while still using `sys.env` in production.

Comment: But how do you expect to test my feature that use sys.env.getOrElse("HOST", "http://localhost:9083") I want to prove that not only the default value but a set env var works here

Comment: That's what I am saying: your feature should not be using `sys.env`. It should take a configuration map as a parameter. Then, in the test, you can just pass `Map("HOST" -> "foobar")` to test it.

Comment: ok to test it as unit test is fine, but I was doing an integration test, but I get what you mean.

Comment: Still I´m curious how to do add a new env var with scala

Comment: For integration test, you set the environment outside of the process, before running the test. You cannot modify environment in scala or in java. Even if it was possible, it would be a very wrong thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's kind of a different question, I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42641730/4686743) applies:
You can't modify the current process' environment (i.e. it's read-only).

As Dima said, you can use a map to save the properties or, like the answer I mentioned suggests, use [scala.util.Properties](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Properties$.html), which gives you access to the current env and allows you to set your own properties.

If using Properties is definitely not an option, and you really need to set some env vars for all the tests, maybe you can use SBT to do that, like this:

```
fork in Test := true
envVars in Test := Map("ENV_VAR" -> "value")
```

The `fork` part is essential. Otherwise, the tests will run in the current process and won't pick up the new env vars.

Comment: Yeah add the env var in our MAVEN was an option indeed