# Setting GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am running Spark-Shell with Scala and I want to set an environment variable to load data into Google bigQuery. The environment variable is `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` and it contains `/path/to/service/account.json`

In python environment I can easily do,

```
import os 
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "path/to/service/account.json"
```

However, I cannot do this in Scala. I can print out the system environment variables using,

```
scala> sys.env
```

or

```
scala> System.getenv()
```

which returns me a map of String Key,Value pairs. However,

```
scala> System.getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS") = "path/to/service/account.json"
```

returns an error

```
<console>:26: error: value update is not a member of java.util.Map[String,String]
```

Comment: have you found a solution ?

Comment: yes, I have found a work around for this.

Comment: can you answer your question with the solution ?

Comment: hey, i answered the question. let me know if it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala: Unable to set environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42639105/scala-unable-to-set-environment-variable)

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for this problem, though I dont think its the best practice. Here is the 2 step solution for this  -

1. From terminal/cmd, first create the environment variable -

   `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=path/to/service/account.json`
2. From the **same** terminal window, open `spark-shell` and run -

   `System.getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS")`